# C++ for-loop - test part

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is an easy question but i am stuck. Here is code for a Quasi Random Number Generator in [this paper](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ettwong/papers/udpoint/udpoint.pdf).

```
void PlaneHammersley(float *result, int n)
{
float p, u, v;
int k, kk, pos;

for (k=0, pos=0 ; k<n ; k++) {

u = 0;
for (p=0.5, kk=k ; kk ; p*=0.5, kk>>=1)
   if (kk & 1) // kk mod 2 == 1
     u += p;
v = (k + 0.5) / n;
result[pos++] = u;
result[pos++] = v;
}
}
```

i try to translate in Python and the second for loop is mysterious to me. The ending condition is `kk` which is an int and I dont know when it evaluates to True. Can someone explain what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I am curious how this code work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent to:

```
for (p=0.5, kk=k ; kk != 0; p*=0.5, kk>>=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer evaluates to true if it's non-zero (i. e. strictly positive or negative).
This also stands for various other types: floating-point values are also true when they're non-zero, and pointers which do not equal to the `NULL` pointer are also considered true.